# Select dynamic checkbox id using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have set of dynamically generated checkboxes. I want to select them by change event. Means get the changed checkbox id.

My PHP/HTML:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category order by categoryodr asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_errno());
while ($valuesca = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo'<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id=' . $valuesca['catid'] . ' onclick="wedCheck(' . $valuesca['catid'] . ')" value="' . $valuesca['catid'] . '"/>&nbsp;';
}
```

My jquery:

```
$('.checkbox').on("#id").change(function() {

var txtval = $(":checkbox").on("#id").val();

});
```

I always get the 1st id on jquery but the html ids are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for your [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call is incorrect:

```
$(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = this.id;
});
```